# Auto scroll to anchor

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have this code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
    $(window).load(function() {
        $(".scroll").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            //calculate destination place
            var dest = 0;
            if ($(this.hash).offset().top > $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
                 dest = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
            } else {
                 dest = $(this.hash).offset().top;
            }
            //go to destination
            $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: dest }, 1000, 'swing');
        });
    });//]]>
</script>
```

How should I do to get the scrolling to such #destination immediately when the page loads instead of as now when I have to click on a link first?

Comment: You can add this to the document read to trigger the click event when the page is loaded ..    $( ".scroll" ).trigger( "click" );

Comment: If you don't need animate affect for scroll on page load, you can just pass your element id in url with # prefixed. Like `www.site.com/page#scroll-here`. It will scroll to the element with id `scroll-here`.

Comment: BwithLove: Thanks but i need the animate affect :/

Comment: In that case, once page loads, you can trigger `click` method for your element as `Bob Tate` said.

Comment: I try this:    $(window).load(function(){
$(".scroll").trigger("click"); 
 $(".scroll").click(function(event){ But not working

Comment: `$(".scroll").trigger("click"); ` call it after `$(".scroll").click(function(event){...});`